# Does AWS has options similar to resilince4j to incorporate Circuitbreaker pattern when a particular service is down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, resilience4j

I would like to know whether it is a good option to implement resilience4j for the circuit breaker pattern on AWS project. My scenario here is, having a microservice hitting dynamo db (single region) and upon facing the transactions getting failed for at least 5 times, we need to redirect the call to make the transaction publish to some other service by enabling resilience4j. So that i cannot miss out any transactions.

Please put in your thoughts to understand how aws handles resiliency with dynamodb, when it is single region (global tables not enabled)

Comment: Global tables are for performance, not resiliency.  By default DynamoDB is already highly available. spread across multiple AZ's in a region.  Please explain more of what you're trying to do as planning against a DynamoDB failure is going to be, for all practical purposes, a nearly impossible thing to happen.

Comment: Thanks! @stdunbar. Adding few more insights on what are we trying to acheive.
1. Having DDB in 1 region (No global tables)
2. In case of DDB unavailability(lets consider the case of region down), the calls to it has to be redirected automatically to some other service.(which we can be lets say s3/sqs/whatever)
3. so to acheive this, the plan is to incorporate circuit breaker pattern with resilience4j. 
Would like to know when we think about resiliency here, what are the options available with aws sdk to enable us with the circuiting?